# Why in incognito mode the page is displayed normally. But in normal mode - no?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I made changes to the site through the Elementor plugin. I look at the page in incognito mode - it is displayed correctly. I look in the normal mode - the layout is break.

I understand that the problem is in the browser cache. But how to solve it?

Here is what I have tried.

1. Found and installed the plugin "Busted!". Judging by the description, it forces the browser to download files and cache again if they have changed. But it didn’t help me.
2. I reset the cache from the Autoptimize plugin - it did not help.
3. I reset the cache from the WP Super Cache plugin - it did not help.
4. Re-create CSS in Elementor -> Tools - did not help.
5. Added this code to the theme header:

   ```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
   ```

Did not help.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening your browser's Developer Tools (hit F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I), go to the Application tab and on the left menu, search for Application > Clear Storage.

Click the 'Clear site data' button and see if that helps.

Comment: I can’t get all website visitors to press Ctrl + F5. Someone will come in and see that the site is clumsy. And leave it.

Comment: Are you sure all of your users are seeing the old cached version of your website? If that's what's happening then you can 'force' newer files to be loaded (like the CSS import) by appending a version number to the end of the file name (for example ?ver=1.1) -- the import should look like this then `<link href="assets/css/style.css?ver=1.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Where can I find an Elementor link?